# Errors when import angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hi I am making one application in MVC 5 with angular and i want to use angular material. Everything working fine except whenever i import angular material it gives me errors like cdk not found, rxjx/operator not found.Below is my package.json, systemjs.config.js and my app.module.ts and yes i install angular material,cdk and animations through npm package manager and i can see material and cdk folder under node_modules folder.

1) Package.json

```html
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~5.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "~2.8.3"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

2) systemjs.config.js

```js
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      'app': 'Client/app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js',
        // CDK  packages
      '@angular/cdk': 'npm:@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        meta: {
          './*.js': {
            loader: 'Client/systemjs-angular-loader.js'
          }
        }
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

3) app.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AllMachines } from './app.service';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatButton } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, FormsModule, MatButton],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [AllMachines],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

4) Error picture

[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv9GQ.png)

Comment: your error pic is not visisble

Comment: You have them in npm under your `devDependencies`. They should be in the above section with your Angular imports. Also, you should be using the most recent stable versions for all on new projects.

Comment: bhaumik click on Error Picture link

Comment: I tried with version 6 same error and i had those in dependencies and it give same kind of error

Comment: use `angular-cli` instead of `system.js` for app configuration.